# What traits/actions must give away a light-sensitive out-dimensioner?

Tags: science-based, alternate-reality, light

There is a sub-dimension of this reality where a race of humanoid people lives in very low light. Their race has done so for hundreds of years - everyone there has no experience of being outside their dimension. However, in recent history (approx. 30 years ago) there was a large upheaval in which some members of the race travelled to Earth, and (importantly) one human travelled to their dimension, and remained there. More than that, he [had a child with the ruler of the race](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InterspeciesRomance).

Cut back to the present. This child is now a teenager with a rebellious streak. For an unspecified reason they have run away from the palace and, using one of only a few instances of a rare device, have escaped from their dimension to Earth (one-way). They knew a fair amount about Earth from their father but have never been there before.

In order to blend in, the teenage royal attends a high school. By an unlucky (for them) coincidence, secret agent Bob is also at that school. He is actually attending the school, but for years has been a mediator agent who worked both independently and under orders to uphold the [Masquerade](http://www.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Masquerade).

Bob is notified that agents from the dark sub-dimension have tracked the escapee to his local area. He begins to search for the outlander by looking for new entrants to the schools in the area, other institutions, etc. But there are many, and the escapee can't be identified by looks alone because they are a half-human hybrid. (Bob can't risk accidentally apprenhending the wrong person and revealing the Masquerade to them.) Bob knows quite a lot about the race and knows that the light sensitivty is likely their biggest weakness.

**Question:** what traits/actions are likely to give away the escapee - or, for that matter, any escapee from that dimension into ours? While Bob is the one looking for said traits/actions, anyone would/could notice them - it's just that Bob is on the lookout. Alternatively, the escapee *could* make a blunder, but I'm looking for something intrinsic to the escapee's nature as... well, an outlander escapee. Something which they can't prevent except by superspy-level infiltration.

Extra notes/clarification:
Bob can't reveal to anyone, in any way, that he's an agent. His local area is crawling with enemy agents who would try to kill him as soon as look at him.

UPDATE: The royal family of the sub-dimension have a kind of hereditary magical power. This is how the escapee managed to get into the school without buying a complete set of fake ID from the Dark Web or whatever - they used befuddlement/enchantment/illusion magic on anyone necessary. (Think how wizards get away with everything in Harry Potter.)

Please comment if you need more!

Comment: This is tenuously worldbuilding, it would be clearer that it's on topic though if you made the question more clearly about the nature of the hybrid rather than about the actions of Bob.

Comment: There is a really big problem which makes your scenario seem improbable. Why didn't they just give Bob a photo of the escapee? Or if photography is unavailible, at least a painting. They were a member of the royal family after all.

Comment: @LuciusQ.User They have magic. Without going into detail about the magic system, there's no way Bob can tell that a person is disguising their appearance using an illusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squinting.

I'm not joking.  I'm a light-sensitive human (so way less light-sensitive than your outworlder), and even *I* go through a lot of life shielding my eyes and/or squinting, especially outdoors.  It's usually involuntary.

Your outworlders will also have a preference for lower light levels; they can't do much about the school, but in their homes they'd use lower-lumen lighting than normal.  (Assume they use lighting at all because the neighbors might drop in.)  They might also seek out special eyeglasses, whether that means tinted (like some albinos in our world wear) or made of materials with different refractive properties.  They'll wear sunglasses wherever possible, sometimes even when others around them aren't.  They'll be particularly sensitive to large reflective surfaces like expanses of fresh-fallen snow.

Answer (score 3):

You can (probably) narrow down targets by noting who's wearing sunglasses when not needed.

Then Bob can use knowledge of *both* worlds to trick escapee to reveal himself; some examples:

- Seeing a mock of a very dangerous (small and harmless-looking) animal unknown to this Earth but widely known to alternate dimension may elicit "strange" behavior.
- Approaching with something "outlandish" would be a giveaway of Bob identity, but can also panic escapee into flight (attempt).
- Bringing in some beloved pet may, again, trick escapee to approach.

In any case there could be physical differences (x-ray scan, DNA test, blood samples) that could confirm suspects before apprehension.

Answer (score 2):

After some thinking about it, it is better to focus not on what a escapee (Let's call them E-ki) from another world has, but rather on what they *lack*. 
First thing that gives out E-ki is their paper trail. 
1.In order to enroll in a school they need some form of ID and it is rather hard to obtain one when you are already a teenager and have no other documents. 
2. Most people study *somewhere* before going to high school. E-ki must either claim to be homeschooled, or lie and lists of graduates for a specific school tend to be publically availible. 
3. E-ki lacks any kind of family in our dimension. So they may either claim to be an orphan (which may contradict the info from pt. 2) or have an adoptive family, and Bob knows the approximate date of the escape.
 4. Nowdays teens tend to have accouts in some kind of social network.  One without any accouts or with a way too recent reg date goes to the suspect bench. 
5. (Applies only to the case where E-ki needs to wear shades). If you wear shades at school without an optician's prescription, teaches will give you funny looks. So, when did E-ki get such a prescription? (Such a condition does not spring out of nowere).

Comment: This makes sense.  It would be an appropriate method to track down any alien.  Also, the kids would know who it was - high schoolers are extremely sensitive to social fluency, which this alien would lack.  He would be known to lack it and would be regarded either as a total dufus who grew up in a Skinner box or a charmingly clueless foreigner.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is possibly not sensitivity to light so much as familiarity and functionality within low light conditions.

Consider constructing a situation in which the subject needs to enter a darkened or low light room to search for something, possibly with some kind of imperative. A human would naturally switch on the light to see better to assist the search, but a light sensitive, with eyes adapted to low light would prefer to search with the light off because their vision would naturally be better in low light conditions, and they would be better composed psychologically to conduct a search without the unpleasant inconvenience and interference of strong lighting.

Of course, the test would have to be unbeknown to the subject and ideally, to their knowledge, unobserved.

Answer (score 1):

Develop some excuse to take photos around the school.  Take flash photos of groups of students.  The ones that react badly are the ones to pay more attention to.

This will narrow down the list of candidates but it will likely not find the person directly since normal (used advisedly) humans, such as myself, can react badly to flashes too.

Then you can use the lights out method that Lee Leon mentioned.

However, as Lucius Q. User pointed out:  How the heck did this kid get enrolled in the first place?

Comment: See my new edit about enrolment